# Using a date as Firestore Document Id?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql, firebase-security

I have a diary App where I want to have a single document for each day. My question is if it would be a good practise to use an ISO 8601 datetime String as a document Id. Because every day can only have one document it would be an unique Id.

Or should I store the date in the document and use a random document Id? What would be a better choice?

One querie I want to do is check if there is an document with a specific date (for example today). If so, I want to fetch this document, otherwhise If there is no document for today I want to create one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the value that you want to be unique as the document ID is an easy (and in many cases the only) way to ensure uniqueness. As long as the limit on throughput for such sequential keys is acceptable for your use-case (which seems to be the case here), it is a good, simple method of ensuring uniqueness.

Comment: Is an ISO 8601 like '2021-11-01T09:12:00.376' an acceptable document id or is '-' or ':' not allowed?

Comment: Yes, that's an acceptable document ID format. But it also sounds like something you could easily try in the Firebase console.

Comment: I tried different things and ended up with this as my best solution: Since every day is unique I want to have the document id '2021-11-01' without time so it makes it easy to query. But what about hotspotting as mentioned here: https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/best-practices?hl=en Will this be an issue?

Comment: If you'd use a random document ID and only store the date in a field, you'd need an index on that field to be able to query on it - and end up with the exact same situation as far as hotspots are concerned. Also: since you talk about a diary app, it seems unlikely you'll end up with prohibitively many writes.

Answer (score 1):

It seems good, however firebase [does not recommend this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/best-practices). This is because using incremental document id names is not recommended. This could be Customer1, Customer2, ... CustomerN, or in your case dates. 10-31-21, 11-1-21, 11-2-21, ... is incremental.

Also, note their second suggestion: Avoid using / forward slashes in document IDs.

> Or should I store the date in the document and use a random document Id? What would be a better choice?

I would chose the latter. Use a random doc id and then store the date inside.

With this being said, best practices and exactly that, best practices. They are not rules. In your case, if using the date as the document id makes it easier and requires less reads, it may be the best choice.

Comment: Thank you, would monotonically increasing be a big problem?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "monotonically increasing"?

Comment: It means that document IDs look like this: Consumer1, Consumer2, ...

Comment: It wouldn't be a problem at at all.

Answer (score 1):

A solution for your use case might be to add a date field and query on that date, where you still would have a unique ID per document.

Query:

```js
      const analyticsCol = await x.ref
        .collection('dishes')
        .where('date', '>=', yesterdayDate)
        .where('date', '<=', new Date()) // today
        .limit(1)
        .get();
    


const getYesterdayDate = () => {
  const yesterdayDate = new Date();
  yesterdayDate.setDate(yesterdayDate.getDate() - 1);
  yesterdayDate.setTime(
    yesterdayDate.getTime() -
      yesterdayDate.getHours() * 3600 * 1000 -
      yesterdayDate.getMinutes() * 60 * 1000
  );
  return yesterdayDate;
};
```

Hope it helps.