# Can I use an ISO-String like '2022-02' as document id in cloud firestore or would this cause hotspotting?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, data-modeling

In my App a user can track his workouts, which I want to save in cloud firestore. My idea is to store a list of workouts for each month to prevent that a document gets too big. So a document would look something like this:

```
month: '2022-02',
workouts: [
  {
  date: '2022-02-01',
  exercises: [
       {
        sets: [{'reps': 12, 'weight': 80}
               {'reps': 12, 'weight': 80}
            ],
       },
     ],
 },
{
  date: '2022-02-02',
  exercises: [
       {
        sets: [{'reps': 10, 'weight': 90}
               {'reps': 10, 'weight': 90}
            ],
       },
     ],
 },
],
```

**Question:**

How to fetch for example the documents of the last three months? What happens if I have lets say 500 documents with an monotionally increasing document ID like an ISO-String 2022-02 for each month. Now I want to fetch all month until 2017-05. Will this cause hotspotting?

What is a good practise when storing data like this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using a date as Firestore Document Id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69789075/using-a-date-as-firestore-document-id)

Comment: Not completely. I edited my question. I hope now its clearer what i am worrying about

Comment: I usually use DateTime.now().toIso8601String() as unique document ids or timestamps for my documents sometimes

Answer (score 0):

The right approach regarding your document IDs is to use the [Uuid](https://pub.dev/packages/uuid) package. So ideally you don't want to use a date for the identifier of your documents.

Regarding the dates, what you need is to use the `where()` clause of Firebase APIs in order to retrieve data in a specific date range.